# How to move ClearCase view to a new domain?

Tags: clearcase

We are in situation where we successfully moved the VOBs from A domain to B domain (ClearCase server is running on Windows and we use one ClearCase server only).
Now we try to change the views permission in order to prevent creating new views, but it seems that they're still on the same domain.

I tried

```
fix_prot -force -replace ...vws

fix_prot -root -rec -chown -chgrp ...vws
```

It works good with no errors, but when I try after to see properties, it's still on \username

Can you advice?
We use snapshot views only

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For snapshot or dynamic views, the [`fix_prot` utility](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21142606) is used like this:

```
fix-prot -force -rec -chown newUserName -chgrp newGroupe -chmod 775 /path/to/view/storage.vws
fix-prot -force -root -chown newUserName -chgrp newGroupe /path/to/view/storage.vws
```

I never use -root -rec: always `-rec` on one side, `-root` on the other.

Note the two warnings:

> It is recommended that ClearCase services on Windows be shut down prior to running the `fix_prot` utility.
>   This will ensure that no files are held open by ClearCase processes which otherwise could be skipped during the execution of the utility.
>
> Note: When you run `fix_prot`, if there are any `Additional Groups` that were part of the VOBs group list, running this command will remove those groups.
>   As a result you will need to run the [`protectvob`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_protectvob.htm?resultof=%22protectvob%22) command to add these additional groups back to the VOB.